# Why does a long, free-to-move object rotate when I push it from one side?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation, moment

I was pushing a pencil along a table top when I noticed that it rotates around the other end.

[image]

Somewhat like this(The dotted red lines show the final position of the pencil).

**The pencil is not pivoted anywhere, so where is the torque coming from? Is the "pivot" being formed due to friction?** But the same friction is acting equally(material of table and the pencil is same) on every point in the body, so **why will the torque be produced only around one end?**

I tried it with other common household objects too(like a rectangular box, a simple wooden stick), obtained same results.

**Where is this "Pivot" being formed, and what is causing its formation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all  there doesn't need to be a "stationary pivot" for there to be a torque. a torque is the angular analogue of force, apply a torque for a time, and you will have a change of angular momentum. an object that is in space, floating, when I press on one end  will start rotating as I have applied a torque. However In this specific scenario, the other end of the pencil doesn't move because of friction, the reaction force of the pencil on the ground also gives it an opposite torque causing it to stop rotating given that I apply a constant torque to the pencil

Comment: "However In this specific scenario, the other end of the pencil doesn't move because of friction, the reaction force of the pencil on the ground also gives it an opposite torque, equal to the applied torque ( for when you keep it stationary)"

But how will reaction of pencil act on ground, if I apply horizontal force on the pencil(parallel to ground/table)?

Comment: the reaction of a pencil given I apply a horizontal force won't change. as the vertical component force is the same, Friction = $\mu$ R doesn't change. applying a horizontal force would in theory apply a torque to the object however.

Comment: obviously if the horizontal force applied overcomes Friction, the torque of  of gravity  along with the force of gravity will cause the pencil to become parralell to the ground   resting on the ground. and if you try to apply a force horizontally to the pencil now, the torque would.he zero as Torque = R  x F or, more simply r*f*sin($\theta$) where theta is the angle between the vector R and the force aka the component perpendicular to R